# SSL is throwing an error within xampp, even on reinstall of Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, xampp

My xampp window is showing this:

```
[Fri Aug 31 20:18:17.001974 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 3812:tid 388] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Aug 31 20:18:17.048852 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 3812:tid 388] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Aug 31 20:18:17.111352 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3812:tid 388] AH00455: Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0h PHP/7.2.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Aug 31 20:18:17.111352 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3812:tid 388] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Jul 11 2018 12:13:24
[Fri Aug 31 20:18:17.111352 2018] [core:notice] [pid 3812:tid 388] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri Aug 31 20:18:17.111352 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3812:tid 388] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4212
[Fri Aug 31 20:18:17.658179 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 4212:tid 404] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Aug 31 20:18:17.689429 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 4212:tid 404] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Aug 31 20:18:17.736308 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4212:tid 404] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Even though I reinstalled xampp, and used a complete fresh install of apache.
Shouldn't the apache reinstall reset the SSL stuff?

Comment: From what I read, this is not done automatically by XAMMP.  See https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1210/19/how-to-generate-a-csr-and-configure-a-certificate-for-use-in-xampp and this https://shellcreeper.com/how-to-create-valid-ssl-in-localhost-for-xampp/